# Finding the second peak in two normally distributed data

Tags: gaussian, data-fitting

I am fitting 2 gaussians to a data. The fitting requires a guessed value of the centers of the peaks as start parameters. I managed to get the first max using the following (the gaussian is defined by 'x' and 'y' in my data):

```
maxd = max(y) #peak
center1 = x[y.argmax(maxd)] #guess of center 1
```

I am now trying to get the guess of the second peak (center 2) for input in my fitting. Any idea to do that?

The thing is that I could do it one-by-one by eye but I am doing fitting in batch for several data structures. So, I need an automated way.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZbBS.png)

Thanks!
Rajeev

Cheers,
Rajeev

Comment: Depending on how different the sigmas and peak heights are it might work if you just subtract the fitted first peak from the data and take the new `max`. PS: very inconvenient choice of variable names.